# ES6 Symbols with Dot Notation

Tags: javascript, syntax, ecmascript-6

In the examples I've seen so far using Symbols in ES6, you have to access symbol properties in Object literals using bracket notation:

```
let mySymbol = Symbol("mySymbol");

let someObject = {
  [mySymbol]: "someValue"
};

console.log(someObject[mySymbol]); // "someValue"
```

Is there a way to define and access symbol properties using dot notation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Symbols must be accessed using bracket notation.

Dot notation is only used for `string` keys that follow certain rule patterns, mostly about being a valid identifier.

Symbols are not strings, they are a whole something else entirely.

Short rational: One of the design goals of symbols is that they can not clash with property names, that makes them safe to use.

So, if you had an object like this

```
var = {
  prop1: "Value"
};
```

And you created a symbol called `prop1`, how could you tell the two apart, and access them differently, using just object notation?

Answer (score 3):

No. Dot notation is reserved for identifiers which resolve to property *names* (strings). And this won't change for backward compatibility reasons.